# R720 Lite-Touch Server 2008 64-bit Install Troubles

Tags: windows-server-2008, dell, dell-poweredge

I am having trouble deploying Windows Server 2008 64-bit using [Lite-Touch](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd919179%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) on a Dell R720.

All goes well until Lite-Touch attempts to partition the hard drive. It then fails indicating that it cannot locate the C:\ drive for writing. I use `F8` to bring up a command prompt, run `diskpart`, `list disk`, the virtual drive I created is not shown.

Is this a driver issue? If so, how can I inject the drivers into the Lite-Touch boot process?

Answer (score 2):

You add drivers to a Windows WIM image using the [Advanced Installation Toolkit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=153774) in the `Microsoft-Windows-PnpCustomizationsWinPE` step. See [this page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744282%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) for more info about where the drivers are added during the installation process.

I'd be a little bit concerned though, as on our R710's we have no additional drivers were needed, although obviously I don't know what your exact configuration is.

Comment: Sorry for all the revisions on this, I don't know if you saw earlier ones, my memory on the subject was very hazy and I've just had to refresh it.

Comment: No problem, thanks for the advice. R720 is the next generation (G12) and there is a different driver set. I do not have ownership over the image. Is there another way I can load the drivers?

Comment: @JSKNS - if this is "light touch", then there should a button on the screen for selecting the installation destination where you add drivers on the fly

Comment: Still no-go. I think my Lite Touch may be a one-off customization. Ill  upvote you for the solid help though.